# Do twelver shia really say one imam stays silent regarding divine guidance when 2 are present?

Tags: shiism, shia-sunni, aqidah, shia-imam

I am informed one imam stays silent regarding divine guidance when 2 are present.

.
Raifidi hadith by Imam Sadiq (RH)

> حدثنا محمد بن الحسين عن الحسن بن محبوب عن العلاء عن عبد الله بن ابى يعفور عن ابى عبد الله عليه السلام قال كان على بن ابى طالب عليه السلام عالم هذه الامة والعلم يتوارث وليس يمضى منا احد حتى يرى من ولده من يعلم علمه ولا تبقى الارض يوما بغير امام منا تفزع إليه الامة قلت يكون امامان قال لا الا واحدهما صامت لا يتكلم حتى يمضى الاول. (Basa'iru d-Darajat of as-Safar al-Qumi)
> Abdu l-Lah ibn Abi Ya'fur said that Abu Abdi l-Lah (Jafaru s-Sadiq) said: "Ali ibn Abi Talib was the knowledgeable Imam of this Ummah and the knowledge is inherited. Not one of us passes away until he sees a son who learns his knowledge, and the Earth doesn't last for a day without an Imam from us, with the Ummah seeking refuge towards him." I said: ***"Can there be two Imams?" He said: "No, unless one of them is silent and refuses to speak until the first one passes away."***

But as per Quran there are atleast 2 instances when 2 imams speak about divine guidance at the same time.

-Quran 36:14

> When ***We sent to them two but they denied them***, so We strengthened [them] with a third, and they said, "Indeed, we are messengers to you."

Another instance is of that Ibrahim and lut.

> But when ***he (ibrahim) saw that they did not stretch out their hands*** towards it, he had a mistrust about them and felt a fear of them in his heart. They said, ***"Don't have any fear: for we have been sent to the people of Lot."***

Quran 11:70.

The doubt arises because twelver shia also considers prophets and messengers as imam.

How do twelver shia reconcile between the instances of Quran and their hadith?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the Shiites do not consider all the prophets and messengers to be Imams, and this position was reserved for a limited number of great prophets such as Ibrahim (as).

When his Lord tested Abraham with certain words and he fulfilled them, He said, ‘I am making you the Imam of mankind.’
Quran: 2 -124

Comment: ***"The earth doesnt last a day without imam"*** is in the hadith

Answer (score 0):

Imamate in Shiite teachings means to lead, and whoever is in charge of group leadership is called "Imam", whether in the way of truth or in the way of falsehood, as in verse 12 of Surah "Repentance" the word "Imams of infidelity" Has been used about infidels. "Imamate" in the term of the theologians is: universal and all-round leadership over the Islamic society in all worldly and otherworldly affairs.
Therefore, the "Imam" is a person who has a public presidency in religious and worldly affairs, and this presidency is a successor to the Messenger of God (PBUH). With such a definition and position, clearly in a single time, only one person can be the Imam and the leader of the public.
This definition mentions only a part of the Imamate officials. The Imam has other matters which are not reflected in the mentioned definition.
In Shiite teachings, there is a conceptual and positional difference between "Rasool", "Nabi" and "Imam".
And it is not that you say "the Twelver Shiites consider all the prophets and messengers as Imams", but the Shiites according to verse 124 of Surah Al-Baqarah believe that the Imamate is a position that has not been given to all the prophets and messengers. Rather, Imamate is a position that God Almighty assigned to Ibrahim Khalil in the third stage after the position of prophethood and revelation (Khalilullah) and it is a virtue that honored him.

https://hawzah.net/fa/Magazine/View/4227/8007/104983/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B3%D9%87-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B1%D8%B6%D8%A7%22%D8%B9%22